# What is the correct way to combine redux-thunk and redux-batched-actions?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-batched-actions

What is the correct way to plug `redux-batched-actions` into my existing Redux store? I am completely confused by the Redux middleware API.

Currently I am using `redux-thunk` and `redux-little-router`.

Here is the code source that creates my Redux store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { routerForBrowser } from 'redux-little-router'
import reducers from './store'
import routes from './routes'

const { reducer, middleware, enhancer } = routerForBrowser({ routes })

// Combine all reducers and instantiate the app-wide store instance
const allReducers = combineReducers({ ...reducers, router: reducer })

// Build middleware (if devTools is installed, connect to it)
const allEnhancers = (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
  ? compose(
      enhancer,
      applyMiddleware(thunk, middleware),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
  : compose(
      enhancer,
      applyMiddleware(thunk, middleware)))

// Instantiate the app-wide store instance
const initialState = window.initialReduxState
const store = createStore(
  allReducers,
  initialState,
  allEnhancers
)
```

The [redux-batched-actions documentation](https://github.com/tshelburne/redux-batched-actions) exposes two usages: `enableBatching` and `batchDispatchMiddleware`. Which one should I use in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after the return of my expedition into the fabulous source code of redux, redux-thunk, redux-batched-actions, ...

The correct way to do it seems to be using `batchDispatchMiddleware`, like this:

```
import { batchDispatchMiddleware } from 'redux-batched-actions'

// ...

const allEnhancers = (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__
  ? compose(
      enhancer,
      applyMiddleware(batchDispatchMiddleware, thunk, middleware),
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
  : compose(
      enhancer,
      applyMiddleware(batchDispatchMiddleware, thunk, middleware)))
```

Note: I don't know if I could dispatch batched thunks, though. I don't do that in my current application. Use at your own risk!